# found the right css using firebug, just don't know the syntax

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to edit the revolution slider plugin on my wordpress site. My images (slides) are not left aligned in the slider div. I found out where I can fix it using Firebug, and I know how to enter it into the custom css on wordpress, but but don't know the exact syntax to designate the proper div/id/class etc.

Video:
http://youtu.be/oyYrKAAAe80

Page in Question:
http://www.billyjacksdesign.com/design-work/the-living-logo/#htbanchor

I made the background of the slider red so the area I'm talking about is obvious, if you look at the other two sliders, you'll see that same area is white, but the div's shadow continues to the left margin--this misalignment is what I'm trying to remove.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following to your stylesheet should work:

```
.rev_slider ul {
margin-left: 0;
}
```

Since the ul tag has a margin-left of 15px, but it doesn't have a class/id, you will need to go up a level which has a class `rev_slider`. Since the ul is in that class you can used `.rev_slider ul`